# C# - Swapping objects without a placeholder

Tags: c#

I was told that using a temp object was not the most effective way to swap elements in an array.

Such as:

```
Object[] objects = new Object[10];
// -- Assign the 10 objects some values
var Temp = objects[2];
objects[2] = objects[4];
objects[4] = Temp;
```

Is it really possible to swap the elements of the array without using another object?

I know that with math units you can but I cannot figure out how this would be done with any other object type.

Comment: Who told you this? Why didn't they show you how?

Comment: With numbers you can "store" two objects in the same element as the sum, but that is not possible with a generic object...

Comment: Whoever told you there is a better way to do this in C# clearly had no idea what he was talking about.

Answer (score 7):

Swapping objects with a temporary is the most correct way of doing it. That should rank way higher up in your priorities than speed. It's pretty easy to write fast software that ouputs garbage.

When dealing with objects, you just cannot do it differently. And this is not at all inefficient. An extra reference variable that points to an already existing object is hardly going to be a problem.

But even with numerical values, most clever techniques fail to produce *correct* results at some point.

Answer (score 3):

Swapping via deconstruction:

```
(first, second) = (second, first);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's *possible* the person who told you this was thinking of something like this:

```
objects[2] = Interlocked.Exchange(ref objects[4], objects[2]);
```

Of course, just because this is one line doesn't mean it isn't *also* using a temporary variable. It's just hidden in the form of a method parameter (the reference to `objects[2]` is copied and passed to the `Exchange` method), making it less obvious.

Comment: It should be using XCHG which doesn't require an intermediate value... though i would be far from surprised if suboptimal code came out of the JIT.

Comment: In any case, if the person in question was thinking of this as *the most effective* way, he was even more clueless than I thought. Synchronizing for the sake of synchronizing (or worse, for the sake of "efficiency") is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

you could do it with Interlocked.Exchange but that won't be faster than using a temp variable... not that speed is likely to matter for this sort problem outside of an interview.

Answer (score 0):

Every example I can find online uses exactly this method to swap 2 elements in an array. In fact, if this were something I were doing often I would definately consider a generic extansion method, akin to this example:

http://w3mentor.com/learn/asp-dot-net-c-sharp/c-collections-and-generics/generically-swapping-two-elements-in-array-using-ccsharp/

Answer (score 0):

The only time you should worry about creating a temporary object is when its massive, and the time taken to copy the object will be sufficiently long and if you're doing it a lot, for example, or if youre doing a sort of 10k items, and moving it from 9999 to 1, 1 stage at a time testing if it should move or not, then swapping it each and every time would be a drain. However, a more efficient way would test all the tests and move once.

Comment: There are no copies involved here, except for a couple of references. Which are probably something like 32- or 64-bit. Not problematic at all to have "massive" objects.

Comment: This doesn't apply to the OP's example, of course. Using a temporary variable to swap two *references* in C# does not "copy" anything but the reference itself; it isn't allocating a new object.

Comment: No, but was trying to give a reason why not to worry.

Comment: this isn't a "real" question though.  Its an interview question asked by someone who read some fancy math on the internet and either doesn't understand it or came up with some frightening way to do it in an unsafe code block.