# How to swap 2 values in a List in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, sorting

So iam new to c# and trying to making a bubble sort algorithm and was wondering is there a way to swap 2 values in a list in the simplest way?

```
static void BubbleSort(List<int> list)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i == list.Count-1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; i == list.Count - i; j++)
                {
                    if (list[j] > list[j+1])
                    {
                      //Need a way to swap values in position j and j+1
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: you could use `Interlocked.Exchange`, or just create a temporary variable.

Comment: @Andy never heard of interlocked.exchange i searched it up but cant find it for listed,could you show how to do it please?

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068856/c-sharp-swapping-objects-without-a-placeholder

Comment: Don't listen to him, interlocked exchange is needlessly expensive and lazy.

Comment: @Blindy -- man, you're a bundle of fun lol

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple, use a temporary variable to momentanly store one of two values:

```
if (list[j] > list[j+1])
{
    int temp = list[j];
    list[j] = list[j+1];
    list[j+1] = temp;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -2):

```
if (list[j] > list[j + 1])
    (list[j], list[j + 1]) = (list[j + 1], list[j]);
```

Comment: I don't want to be "that guy", but could you explain what this is doing?

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @Blindy hey i tried your error and now it shows me an out of index error

Comment: @Blindy ```
      List<int> list = new List<int> { 3, 1, 7, 5, 2 };

      BubbleSort(list);
    }
    static void BubbleSort(List<int> list)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i <= list.Count-1; i++)
      {
        for (int j = 0; j <= list.Count - i; j++)
        {
          if (list[j] > list[j+1])
          {
              // can just swap values otherwise causes issues
              int temp = list[j];
              list[j] = list[j + 1];
              list[j + 1] = temp;
          }
        }
      }
      Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", list));
    }

Comment: If you are trying to read this code and your eyes are getting crossed, it uses _Tuples_.  If you have N values surrounded by parens, it represents a Tuple in modern C#.  The right-hand side (RHS, as opposed to LHS) creates a tuple with two value (what at the `j+1` position in the list and what's at the `j` position). That's assigned to the tuple on the LHS, effectively assigning the values to the variables that make up the LHS tuple.  In the end, this is the same as `list[j] = list[j+1]` and `list[j+1] = list[j]` happening simultaneously (without the need for the temporary you'd normally need)

Comment: Im team parentesis magic need explanation. Im also in the team. if this is any good this should find home on a upvoted good question.

Comment: @Flydog57: You're on the right track, but to be nitpicky the LHS isn't a Tuple: it's a pair of assignments wrapped in deconstruction syntax.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I didn't have enough characters to get into deconstructors.  It's tuple-ish!